# SEO and A/B testing for product sorting

Tags: seo, a-b-testing

I have read some articles on this matter: [this](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2012/08/website-testing-google-search.html) and [this](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7238431?hl=en).

One thing caught my attention is **No cloaking**. If we serve two different set of products for different users (and bot, we will just ignore user-agent). How does that going to impact our ranking and indexing?

Answer (score 1):

The article you referenced specifically states not to cloak for user-agent. So, as long as you're selecting which visitors get which version by something other than user-agent, cloaking isn't happening and you are safe.

The article also states how to make sure the correct version of your pages are indexed - by including canonicals. This will make sure bots don't include both versions of your page or one of the variants that doesn't end up winning.

Final suggestion: look into Google Optimize. It's a free service, and by using Google's own service, you can be even more certain that your testing won't cause issues with rankings or indexing in Google specifically.